# RSpec 2.13 warning: previous definition of subject was here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just upgraded to RSpec 2.13 and am seeing two different warnings when running my specs:

```
/Users/peterbrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:120: warning: method redefined; discarding old subject
/Users/peterbrown/code/classy_enum/spec/classy_enum/active_record_spec.rb:63: warning: previous definition of subject was here
```

I suspect it has something to do with how I am looping over an array and defining a new subject each time:

```
describe DefaultDog do    
  context "with valid breed options" do
    [:golden_retriever, 'golden_retriever', Breed::GoldenRetriever.new, Breed::GoldenRetriever].each do |option|
      subject { DefaultDog.new(:breed => option) }
      it { should be_valid }
      its(:breed) { should be_a(Breed::GoldenRetriever) }
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a problem with defining a subject in a loop like this?

*Update:*

I should also note that I'm running my specs with the `-w` option:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.ruby_opts = "-w"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `context` within your loop:

```
describe DefaultDog do    
  [:golden_retriever, 'golden_retriever', Breed::GoldenRetriever.new, Breed::GoldenRetriever].each do |option|
    context "with valid breed option #{option}" do
      subject { DefaultDog.new(:breed => option) }
      it { should be_valid }
      its(:breed) { should be_a(Breed::GoldenRetriever) }
    end
  end
end
```

I believe that writing tests that involve iterating over collections this way means that you will execute a separate test for every item in the collection, versus just performing one test that loops through a collection (hence redefining the subject).   I think this is an understated gotcha in RSpec that caused me much confusion until fairly recently.